# Append header and Footer to the csv data

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I need to export data to CSV using a stored procedure. I am using the `bcp.exe` utility to export data

```
select @sql = 'bcp dbo.Customers out c:\bcp\customers.txt -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

I need to add a header with the column names and a text `File Ended`' at the end of the CSV.

Table structure is like this

```
ID    Name
 1    'joe'
 2    'jon'
```

In CSV it should be like this

```
ID,Name
1,joe
2,jon
END_OF_FILE
```

I have created a view that will have column header and data

```
select 'ID' as ID , 'Name' as Name 
union all 
select ID, Name from Customer
```

I need to append `File Ended` at the end of the CSV

Any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need some more processing.  For example, these DOS commands would create a file `customers2.txt` with a header and footer:

```
echo Header Line > c:\bcp\customers2.txt
type c:\bcp\customers.txt >> c:\bcp\customers2.txt
echo Footer Line >> c:\bcp\customers2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'ID' as ID , 'Name' as Name 
union all 
select cast(ID as varchar(max)), Name from Customer
union all
select 'End of file', ''
```

or even better:

```
SELECT 'ID, Name' as line
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(ID as varchar(max))+', '+Name FROM Customer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'End of file'
```